# Which json library should I use to pass my array of objects (javascript) to the server (java) and vice versa?

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have an array of objects in javascript and I know that I need to use json to pass it to server, but I don't know which library I should use. I found in  this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329860/how-to-store-temporary-data-at-the-client-side-and-then-send-it-to-the-server), that I have to use **JSON.stringify**() function; , but there's also a comment that says that  JSON.stringify is not a standard function and I should use json2.js instead.
What I'd like to know is :

1. Is there any pre-installed Json library in javascript?
2. Which is the best Json library I can use in javascript as well as in java.
3. And... if it´s not too much to ask... where can I get those libraries

thanks beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a JSON property in the global object for browsers using the ECMAScript v5 specification (Dec 09).
2. If it's in both Java and JavaScript then it's not the same library... Personally, I usually use Jackson in Java and ExtJS in Javascript.
3. [Here](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and [here](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/). A much more lightweight js implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: JSON is supported natively in all modern browsers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation#Native_JSON.

Comment: @Zach - Corrected. Assuming a modern browser is not generally valid though.

Comment: @OrangeDog Sure, it depends on the application though. I agree that for a public-facing website, it probably makes sense to target all browsers out there so as not to lose some percent of possible viewers. For that application, you'd want to use a JSON library to ensure functionality.

Comment: thanks OrangeDog, using Json2 was easy, but now that I trying to parse the string in Json format I got from the client, I got this error message:"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper" and this is the code I'm using: ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); List<CompraDetalle> lcd = (List<CompraDetalle>) mapper.readValue(ldc, CompraDetalle.class);

Comment: @eddy - The error means that the Jackson jars are not on the classpath.

Comment: @OrangeDog- since you said you usually use Jackon and if it's not too much to ask, could you please see this post?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392326/problem-when-trying-to-use-jackson-in-java

Answer (score 1):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation#Using_JSON_in_Ajax and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation#Native_JSON.

JSON is supported natively in modern browsers (and in older browsers through eval(), but with possible security and perf implications). http://json.org/ provides a list of JSON libraries for older browsers where native JSON is not supported and the use of eval() is not a good idea.