# Generics with Spring RESTTemplate

Tags: java, spring, generics, jackson, resttemplate

I have a class like that:

```
public class Wrapper<T> {

 private String message;
 private T data;

 public String getMessage() {
    return message;
 }

 public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
 }

 public T getData() {
    return data;
 }

 public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
 }

}
```

and I use resttemplate as follows:

```
...
Wrapper<Model> response = restTemplate.getForObject(URL, Wrapper.class, myMap);
Model model = response.getData();
...
```

However it throws a:

```
ClassCastException
```

I read that: [Issue when trying to use Jackson in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392326/problem-when-trying-to-use-jackson-in-java) but didn't help. There are some topics related to my problem etc.: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7002 and https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7023

Any ideas?

**PS:** My error is that:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to a.b.c.d.Model
```

I think resttemplate can not understand my generic variable and maybe it accepts it as an Object instead of generic T. So it becomes a LinkedHashMap. You can read from it [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) It says that when explaining from what it marshalls to:

> JSON Type | Java Type
>
> object    | LinkedHashMap

Comment: Plz put the exception trace as well.

Comment: I suppose solution for this is added in 3.2 [SPR-7023](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7023)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm using ParameterizedTypeReference and while it works when I pass in Map<String, String> it doesn't work when I pass in my concrete class that represents `data` in your model.

Comment: Did you a find a solution??

Answer (score 175, accepted):

ParameterizedTypeReference has been introduced in 3.2 M2 to workaround this issue.

```
Wrapper<Model> response = restClient.exchange(loginUrl, 
                          HttpMethod.GET, 
                          null, 
                          new ParameterizedTypeReference<Wrapper<Model>>() {}).getBody();
```

However, the postForObject/getForObject variant was not introduced.

Comment: I tried another optioned for your guys,@alexanoid . Just first get the response as `String` ,then use Jackson to parse the string to generics object ,see : 
`String body = restTemplate.exchange(request,String.class).getBody();
  ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
  DataTablesOutput<EmployeeResponse> readValue = mapper.readValue(body, DataTablesOutput.class);`

Comment: Why Model cannot here be also generic?, etc. like this: `Model<InnerModel>`

Comment: To complement Alter's answer you can use:
`mapper.readValue(body, new TypeReference<Wrapper<Model>>(){});`

Comment: My question also why we can't make Model also generic here ?

Answer (score 13):

The only thing I think you could do is creating a new class that extends Wrapper and uses model as a generic.

```
class WrapperWithModel extends Wrapper<Model>{};

WrapperWithModel response = restTemplate.getForObject(URL, WrapperWithModel.class);
```

It's not the best solution, but at least you won't have to unmarshall manually the response.

Comment: I personally don't like this solution but right now I can't upgrade spring to use its new parameterizedtype object (https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7023), so this is good enough. thanks

Comment: it must be static class

Answer (score 2):

Do not use generics with RestTemplate. Wrap request and response object with wrapper object that will hide the generics.