# Spring RestTemplate Equivalent

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am using Spring Resttemplate and have an issue about generics: [Generics with Spring RESTTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108887/generics-with-spring-resttemplate) I want to look at other equivalent libraries that I can handle that situation.

Are there any other choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Jersey Framework (which has both client and server REST APIs): http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html