# Deserialise nested JSON object with dynamic field name

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I'm using Spring RestTemplate and Jackson 2.1 and I'm trying to deserialise the JSON string below. Whereas the first number is an unique ID so this will be dynamic:

```
{"2127388":{"name":"John","city":"Amsterdam","country":"The Netherlands"}}
```

With RestTemplate I do the following:

```
final ResponseEntity<UserDetailsWrapper> re = restTemplate.getForEntity(apiUrl, UserDetailsWrapper.class);
```

The POJO's I have are

```
class UserDetailsWrapper {
    private long uniqueId; // [getter + setter]
    private UserDetails userDetails; // [getter + setter]

    // no args constructor + all properties constructor
}

class UserDetails {
    private String name; // [getter + setter]
    private String city; // [getter + setter]
    private String country; // [getter + setter]

    // no args constructor + all properties constructor
}
```

The UserDetailsWrapper class gets instantiated but all its properties remain null.

When I simply do:

```
{"name":"John","city":"Amsterdam","country":"The Netherlands"}
```

I am able to deserialise to the UserDetails class with all properties filled as expected, so my configuration should be in order. Probably I need to have the UserDetailsWrapper class annotated at specific places or I need to have a custom deserialiser. I tried both but to be honest I have no clue what to do precisely.

If someone can help me out with this I will be a happy man again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the class name, you really don't want a `Wrapper`, you want a `Map`, something like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18014407/785663

Instead of the `String` they use there, use `Long` (untested):

```
TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
MapType mapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(HashMap.class, Long.class, UserDetails.class);
HashMap<Long, UserDetails> map = mapper.readValue(json, mapType);
```

Digging into the code this exactly what RestTemplate does internally by calling `TypeFactory.constructType` with your provided type, unfortunately losing your generics on the way:

```
restTemplate.getForEntity("apiUrl", Map.class);
```

You're [not alone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8108887/785663) in noticing the lack of generics support and the linked answers points to what you've already found:

```
restTemplate.exchange("apiUrl", 
        HttpMethod.GET,
        null,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<Long, UserDetails>>(){});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me further. I posted my final solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I've basically solved it by using a HashMap and then get the first entry of the map.

```
final ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<Long, UserDetails>> ptr =
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<Long, UserDetails>>(){};

final ResponseEntity<Map<Long, UserDetails>> re =
    restTemplate.exchange("apiUrl", HttpMethod.GET, null, ptr);
```

Because RestTemplate::getForEntity() doesn't support adding a type reference I had to use RestTemplate::exchange()

Answer (score 0):

Payload reflecting your POJO structure would be:

```
{"uniqueId":"2127388", "userDetails":{"name":"John","city":"Amsterdam","country":"The Netherlands"}}
```

I don't think it's a good idea to have variable JSON property name (in your case 2127388). Just change the payload structure and use your POJOs as they are.

**Reaction on comment:**

I would personally reconsider using such API, as it's obviously pretty bad API. According [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/), name of the property should be string, whereas here it is obviously semantically meant as number.

If you are forced to use it, just use `Map<String, UserDetail>` as your wrapper. It will obviously have just one element anyway.

Comment: Too bad I can't change the payload, it's provided by a third party API.