# ObjectMapper parsing issue in rest template

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

Below is the class structure:

Response.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Response implements Serializable{

  private final static long serialVersionUID = 8875657894025733696L;

  @JsonProperty ("status")
  public String status;

  @JsonProperty("payload")
  public Payload payload;
}
```

Payload.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Payload<T> implements Serializable {

  private final static long serialVersionUID = 1732258949055126977L;

  @JsonProperty ("data")
  public List <T> data;
}
```

Here `T` is generic class

```
 Response response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, Response.class);
```

What could be JavaType or TypeReference to replace `Response.class` in the above statement, so that I can directly get a `List` of `T` by `response.getPayload().getData();`? Currently it is coming as `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: the thing that really matters here is your JSON. let's see that, please.

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21158245/8089107

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are asking about is whether you can determine (at runtime) the actual type of an object to be deserialized. Jackson allows you to do this, with some extra annotations. I was curious how this worked, and wrote a [sample program](https://github.com/abatkin/PolymorphicJson) a few years ago to test it out.

Note that there a few different options (see [JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) for more details) and I've chosen to implement only one of them.

In my sample, I just annotated the parent class with the property to use to figure out which subclass is being deserialized, and which values map to each possible subclass:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Pet.class, name="pet"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child.class, name="child")
})
public abstract class Parent {...}
```

Comment: This is something different. I tried but not able to succeed. Let me know if you need any more info