# Map to Map<String, Integer> from restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I do restTemplate call and receive rawMap. From debug I see that key class and value class are String. Its ok because service that response to my restTemplate sends map in JSON. Now I want to crate Map  with this code:

```
Map<String, Integer> gameIdsMap = new HashMap<>();
rawGameIdsMap.forEach(((key, value) -> gameIdsMap.put(String.valueOf(key), Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(value)))));
```

Im curious. Is there more efficient and more clear way to do it?
I cant just receive from restTemplate `Map <String,Integer>`.

RestTemplate

```
Map rawGameIdsMap = Objects.requireNonNull(restTemplate.getForObject(uriFactory.getReverseGameIdsURI(), Map.class));
```

Comment: I'm note sure, but somthing like that may work `Map<String, Integer> casted = raw.parallelStream().map(Map::put);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108887/generics-with-spring-resttemplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RestTemplate` class provides several `exchange()` methods.
It allows to specify as parameter an instance of `ParameterizedTypeReference` which the aim is to capture and pass a generic type. 
So you could do something like :

```
Map<String, String> gameIdsMap = Objects.requireNonNull(
    template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
    }).getBody());
```

Doing it :

```
Map<String, Integer> gameIdsMap= Objects.requireNonNull(
    template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Integer>>() {
    }).getBody());
```

is aslo correct (at least with Jackson) but if the value cannot be converted to an `Integer`. In this case, it will provoke a deserialiaztion exception at runtime.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Do you have a Jackson/Gson reference or a concrete example that shows that such a thing? Sorry, not time to write a real test now.

Comment: I have a doubt for the last one with `exchange()` of Spring template. I will give it a go.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I checked that. It works as you said. At least with Jackson. I would delete my answer but cannot since it is accepted. I updated for at least to be conform to the reality.