# Java Stream: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class RealmRole

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stream, java-stream

In my springboot project I have a module named

> model

Here I have a class RealmRole:

```
public class RealmRole {

private String id;
private String name;

public RealmRole() {
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RealmRole{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

From a request I get a

```
List<RealmRole>
```

Now I want to filter a RealmRole by name:

```
realmRoleList.stream().filter(realmRole.getName().equals("user")).forEach(sout)
```

This causes the error:

> Message: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class
> de.test.userregistration.model.RealmRole
> (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
> de.test.userregistration.model.RealmRole is in unnamed module of
> loader 'app')

Even if I just try:

`realmRoleList.stream().forEach(sout)` I get the same error.

I've alread read some questions but I could not find an answer for this issue.
I already removed devtools from pom.xml because I've read that this could lead to classloader problems.

Comment: Did you mean you get an error when you use `realmRoleList.stream().filter(realmRole -> realmRole.getName().equals("user")).forEach(System.out::println);` ?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I updated the question

Comment: You *think* you have a `List<RealmRole>` but in reality you don't. Generics can only ensure type safety at compile time but I guess at runtime the deserialization of your request does not work as you expect it and instead of deserializing your request into a `List<RealmRole>` you get a `List<LinkedHashMap>` instead :-)

Comment: But after the request I a valid List with entities. Now the error occurs even if I do just a simple for loop (for RealmRole realmRole: realmRoleList). It seems you are right but wth is the list looking ok

Comment: Can you add the code that receives the request?

Comment: I solved it and @Smutje was right. It still confusing to me but the response returns a RealmRole [ ] instead of a List but it is deserialized in a list and passed in my code as such.

Comment: Sadly this is one of the many problems with Generics in Java, backwards compatibility and such... :-)

Comment: I assume you're retrieving the list from a request with a RestTemplate. If so have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21158245/2380948) in a similar question. I ran into the same problem.

Comment: No I changed to the webClient because restTemplate won‘t be supported in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question trying to find an answer to this exact problem and couldn't find anything. So I figured I would answer this with my solution.

I was having this issue when I was saving my object as JSON and then trying to retrieve the JSON from Redis. I don't think the class/type of the JSON can be determined so it is loaded into a LinkedHashMap. I fixed this by modifying the Bean for the ObjectMapper which is what Jackson is using to serialize and deserialize.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator.instance, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);

    return objectMapper;
}
```

What this is doing is adding the class information when you save the JSON into Redis so the class/type of the object is known when retrieving data from Redis.

Answer (score -1):

Use this 'collect(Collectors.toList())' at the end to convert the result back to a list.

Comment: I already tried this but it resolves in the same error. Therefor I've split up the stream to see if there is a problem at a certain stage