# What to specify in the responseType parameter of the exchange RestTemplate method

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I'm trying to form a request

```
private final RestTemplate httpClient;
ResponseEntity<DataEntity<User>> response =
    httpClient.exchange(Url,
    HttpMethod.POST, 
    httpEntity,
    User.class);
```

And I get an error

```
Required type:ResponseEntity<DataEntity<User>>
Provided:ResponseEntity<User>
```

What do I need to specify in this parameter?

```
DataEntity - это класс обертка
public class DataEntity<T>{
    private T data;
}
```

What should I specify instead User.class ?

Comment: You have mentioned ` User.class` as responseType . Please change this line `ResponseEntity<DataEntity<User>> response` to this `ResponseEntity<User> response`.

check this link for your reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

Comment: I need the ResponseEntity<Data Entity<User>> response to be in the response. That 's what I need to replace 'User.class `?

Comment: Please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108887/generics-with-spring-resttemplate