# Json string to HashMap can not deserialize

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
{"Messages":[{"KEY01":"VALUE01"}, {"KEY02":"VALUE02"}, {"KEY03":"VALUE03"}]}
```

This is my json string. Im trying to map it to hashmap. This is what im doing:

```
messageByLanguage = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MessageByLanguage.class);
```

This my MessageByLanguage class:

```
public class MessageByLanguage {

@JsonProperty("Messages")
private Map<String, String> messages = new HashMap<String, String>();

public MessageByLanguage (){};

public void setMessages(Map<String, String> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}

public Map<String, String> getMessages() {
    return messages;
}

can not deserialize instance of java util linkedhashmap out of start_array token
```

Thats what error I get. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392326/issue-when-trying-to-use-jackson-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your input is a map from a string to an array, and that array is a collection of objects, each of which has a single key->value (at least in your example).

If you really need a map of those key->value pairs, then you will need to:

1. read in the entire object. If you really want to do this as a single object, it is a `Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>>`, although you could also create an object that handles some of this.
2. convert the array to a map. You'll need to write the code for this yourself, but it means iterating through the list and taking the key,value pair from the map and putting it into a new Map.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

**For Following Json**

```
String json="{\"Messages\":[{\"KEY01\":\"VALUE01\"}, {\"KEY02\":\"VALUE02\"}, {\"KEY03\":\"VALUE03\"}]}";
```

**You need to Modify your parsing in this way**

```
Gson gson=new Gson(); 
Map<String,Map<String,String>> map=new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
map=(Map<String,Map<String,String>>) gson.fromJson(json, map.getClass());
System.out.println(map.keySet());
System.out.println(map.values());
```

**Now Output**

```
[Messages] //Key in String
[[{KEY01=VALUE01}, {KEY02=VALUE02}, {KEY03=VALUE03}]] // Value in Map<String,String>
```

**Now to Get the acutal set of keys and values for Messages**

**Iterate this way**

```
for(Map.Entry<String,Map<String,String>>entry:map.entrySet()){
ArrayList<Map<String,String>>list=(ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) entry.getValue();
    for(Map<String,String>innerMap:list){
        System.out.print(innerMap.keySet()+"\t");
        System.out.println(innerMap.values());
    }
}
```

**Your final Output**

```
[KEY01] [VALUE01]
[KEY02] [VALUE02]
[KEY03] [VALUE03]
```

Comment: this throws the same exception, except now it says "can not eserialize string out of start array token"

Comment: Can you show what is the exact output are you searching for ?

Comment: I need a HashMap<String, String> so I can search for specific key, and output according value;